# Reading the length of a string without using a built-in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think I need to use `for` loop but I just can't wrap my head around it. How should I use it?

I really appreciate even if you give me a hint. Thanks

Comment: Why!? Please, in the name of all that is sacred, tell us *why*!

Comment: @LutzHorn: because it's homework.

Comment: Yes it is a homework. But learning programming languages and creating something is my passion and I love it. I ask my questions here not just for the sake of finishing my homework. I ask my questions here because I want to learn! I am hungry for knowledge!

Comment: How can I avoid my questions getting - points?

Comment: You must answer [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) . Have you ever try to solve it by yourself and what steps you tired and failed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No builtin functions involved. Simple `for` loop.

```
length = 0
for char in myString:
    length += 1
print(length)
```

If you just should not use `len`, you can use that.

```
print(sum(1 for char in myString))
```

Or you can use `reduce` like this

```
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + 1, myString, 0))
```

Comment: this is supposed to be python 3, fix it..

Comment: @KDawG Thanks :) Fixed the `print` statements

Comment: Also remember that you need to import `reduce()` from `functools`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks man :) I updated it

Comment: Using `sum()` or `reduce()` would count as using a built-in I suspect. `for` should be fine though.

Comment: @martineau Yup. Thats why I gave this Note: `If you just should not use len, you can use this` :)

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import count, dropwhile
>>> s = "abc"
>>>  next(dropwhile(lambda i: s[i:], count()))
3
```

(Yes, I know this has quadratic runtime.)

Comment: No built-ins allowed.

Comment: Thank you :) Yes, built-ins are not allowed.